# How do i append data from one table with data from another table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need to add information to a column where the first name, last name, state, and zip match each other from 2 different tables. The current query i am using i do not thing is efficient enough, it is taking days to run and never seems to finish. I have columns from both tables indexed.

```
UPDATE Table_1 INNER JOIN
       Table_2
       ON Table_2.fn = table_1.fn and Table_2.ln = table_1.ln and
          Table_2.State = table_1.state and table_2.zip = table_1.zip
    SET Table_1.app_phone = table_2.phone
```

I have also tried the where statement to do this query and was unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to run effectively, then you need a composite index.  I would suggest:  `table2(fn, ln, state, zip, phone)`.

The composite index should greatly help performance.